# Routing with MVC and Webforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-routing

I am experiencing a routing issue with a webforms site to which I recently added MVC. Webforms is the default part of the site.

Here is my `RouteConfig.cs` code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{myWebForms}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "WebFormDefault1",
            "",
            "~/default.aspx"
        );
    }
```

If I put the `routes.MapPageRoute` before the `routes.MapRoute` I find that my MVC pages will often come back containing ASPX pages.  Having the `routes.MapPageRoute` at the end solves my problems, except if you go to the site at the root (`http://localhost:12345`) it returns a 404 instead of loading `Default.aspx`.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you set `<defaultDocument enabled="true">` in web.config? If default document is not specified, it is possible that MVC routing tried to redirect into index page defined in default route.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, I tired your suggestion, with no luck. It still returns a 404.

Comment: I found this solved the same issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042892/url-routing-c-sharp-mvc-and-web-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Routing C# mvc and Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042892/url-routing-c-sharp-mvc-and-web-forms)