# Adding WebForm to MVC application to work with extension less webform page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an MVC application in which  I have to integrated few webforms pages.

I simply added a webform "WebForm.aspx" to root  and it worked without any issue when I accessed webform with file exetension `http://localhost:54363/WebForm.aspx` but same files doesnt work when I try to access it without file extension `.aspx`

`http://localhost:54363/WebForm` for this is get `404 error`.

For this to work I made changes to Global.asax file as per the this [article](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/3/adding-aspnet-webforms-into-aspnet-mvc-project-and-vice-versa) but it didnt work

Below is the code of Global.asax file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }


        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebPage}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");


            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    "Default", // Route name
            //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            //);

            routes.MapPageRoute("home", "WebForm/", "~/WebForm.aspx", false,
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                        { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
                    });

        }
    }


}
```

Am I going something wrong in the above code or what is the correct way of setting route for WebForm.aspx file.

UPDATE:

I managed to solve this by adding webform route code also in RouteConfig.cs file also

```
using AlhabtoorTennisAcademy.CustomFilters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // webforms page route
            //Custom route code for webform
            routes.MapPageRoute("home", "WebForm", "~/WebForm.aspx", false,
              new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });
}
}
........
```

Comment: Don't remove default MVC routing, just keep it in place but on the last order. I think you should enable somewhat named `EnableFriendlyUrls()` and place `MapPageRoute` on the top order.

Comment: Also try [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx/) to check which route has been taken by `/WebForm` path.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see on the example above, you're adding `MapPageRoute` after the default MVC routing with `MapRoute`, hence the order of `MapPageRoute` is processed after `MapRoute`, which is wrong because routes are processed from top-most to bottom-most order (most-specific to least-specific).

In order to route webforms pages, the `MapPageRoute` must precede `MapRoute` on the top order:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

    // webforms page route
    routes.MapPageRoute("home", "WebForm", "~/WebForm.aspx", false,
        new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
    });

    // default MVC route
    routes.MapRoute(
       "Default", // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

**Additional note:**

You can use placeholder for page names to map all webforms pages in a single `MapPageRoute` definition:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("home", "{WebPage}", "~/{WebPage}.aspx");
```

Related issue:

[URL Routing C# mvc and Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042892/url-routing-c-sharp-mvc-and-web-forms)

Comment: Just tried it it with the code, its not work and returns `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` error for `http://localhost:54363/WebForm` and when i use `.aspx` then it works..

Comment: I managed to solve this by adding following code `routes.MapPageRoute("home", "WebForm", "~/WebForm.aspx", false,
              new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });` in RouteConfig.cs file